# dynamically loaded form controls & links not clickable

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, button, textbox

- Content loaded through AJAX into a div isn't clickable until the user zooms the page. This seems to reset or remap some clickable zone definition somewhere.
- In some other cases, the "clickable zone" gets just a bit off and you can notice it as the mouse cursor changes in the wrong area, not under my input fields/buttons/links.
- This issue is seen under Chrome and Mozilla, I'm not working with IE but it also happens there.

From the symptoms above, what can be the causes?

This is the code I'm using to load the elements, (I doubt it's too relevant since the content is effectively being loaded):

```
function reqHandler(xhr, section) {
    var x = xhr;
    var s = section;
    this.callback = function() {
        if (x.readyState == 4) {
            var ss = document.getElementById(s);
            if (ss != null) 
                ss.innerHTML = x.responseText;
            stripAndExecuteScript(x.responseText);
        }
    }
};


function loadInto(page,section, wait) {
    if (wait==null) wait = true;
    if (wait) makeWait(section);    
    xhr = createXMLHttpRequest();
    handler = new reqHandler(xhr, section);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = handler.callback;
    xhr.open("GET", page, true);
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

stripAndExecute is just to eval the loaded content's javascript, but it isn't used, the loaded content has simple link tags and a form, but anyway here's the code:

```
function stripAndExecuteScript(text) {
    var scripts = '';
    var cleaned = text.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gi, function(){
        scripts += arguments[1] + '\n';
        return '';
    });

    if (window.execScript){
        window.execScript(scripts);
    } else {
        eval(scripts);  

    }
    return cleaned;
}
```

HTML of the generated div content:

```
<form id="users_form">
    <table>
        <colgroup><col width="65px">
        </colgroup><tbody><tr>
            <td colspan="2">Llene todos los campos</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Nombre</td>
            <td><input class="text_field" name="name" value="" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">E-Mail</td>
            <td><input class="text_field" name="email" value="" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Usuario</td>
            <td><input class="text_field" name="user" value="" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Contraseña</td>
            <td><input class="text_field" name="password" type="password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Repita contraseña</td>
            <td><input class="text_field" name="password_confirm" type="password"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="type_display_block">
            <td align="right">Tipo</td>
            <td><select class="text_field" name="type" style="width:100%;">
                    <option value="0">Administrador</option>
                    <option value="1">Gerente</option>
                    <option value="2">Normal</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr><tr>       
            <td colspan="2"><a class="button" style="float: right;" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="doDBinsert();"><img alt="Enviar" src="http://localhost/eclipse/mensajesInternos/img/check.png" height="25px" width="25px">Enviar
            </a></td>


        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</form>
```

The element which becomes not clickable is the "Enviar" button in the bottom.

NOTE: I'm not using jQuery.

NOTE2: If I put the "Enviar" link not in the next row but in the next column next to the select, like this:

```
<tr class="type_display_block">
            <td align="right">Tipo</td>
            <td><select class="text_field" name="type" style="width:100%;">
                    <option value="0">Administrador</option>
                    <option value="1">Gerente</option>
                    <option value="2">Normal</option>
            </select></td>

            <td colspan="2"><a class="button" style="float: right;" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="doDBinsert();"><img alt="Enviar" src="http://localhost/eclipse/mensajesInternos/img/check.png" height="25px" width="25px">Enviar
            </a></td>


        </tr>
```

this is, in a TD instead of a TR, the element "Enviar" is clickable again. Actually I discovered the Select controls are responsible for the wrong offset in other sections as well. This is reproducible under windows and linux in Mozilla Firefoz and Chrome.

A bug of some kind?...

Comment: What does `stripAndExecute()` do?

Comment: I just edited to explain that function, but with my test case now it basically does nothing.